# Libreoffice Calc Copy Formula Along Row Without Offseting The Functions Column Variables

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

I have a calc file with two spreadsheets in it. One that is called 'Master' has column A filled with text values. I need to copy those values onto the second spreadsheet along a row by using a formula like =$master(A1), however when you copy the formula along a row it also changes the variables to move along the row as well so instead of thew next cell being $master(A2) it ends up being $master(B1). How can you Keep the column the same but only increment the number? Like $master($A+COLUMN)

If tried OFFSET and INDIRECT but I cant get those to increment correctly either. It seems to me you should be able to do something like $master."A"&1 but that doesn't increment at all.

Answer (score 0):

OFFSET should work fine, but you need to use the current COLUMN -1 as the offset for the row:

```
=OFFSET(master.$A$1;COLUMN()-1;0)
```

The -1 is needed since you start at the first column, but want to have an offset of 0. If you start at another column, adjust the subtraction accordingly.

Copy the formula along the row.